# Running SQL With VB.NET Produces No Output

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've been trying to create a program that can manipulate Microsoft Access from within VB.NET. I've seen/read tutorials on how you can run SQL commands through VB.NET, however the code I've made makes absolutely no changes when run. No errors crop up mind you, just nothing happens.

More specifically I'm trying to get the program to first make a new table in Access from within the program. Here's the code:

First the initial lines that call the function:

```
Private Sub ViewJanuary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ViewJanuary.Click
    ImportFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    ImportFileName = ImportFileDialog.FileName
    ImportSheet3(ImportFileName, "January")
End Sub
```

And then the actual code for making a connection and (ideally) making a new table.

```
Sub ImportSheet3(ByVal ImportFileName As String, ByVal Month As String)
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ImportFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0';")
        MyConnection.Open()
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(
        "CREATE TABLE " + Month + Convert.ToString(YearSelected) + "
        (
        ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Field1 VARCHAR(63),
        Field2 VARCHAR(63),
        Field3 VARCHAR(63),
        Field4 VARCHAR(63),
        Field5 VARCHAR(63),
        Field6 VARCHAR(63),
        Field7 VARCHAR(63),
        Field8 VARCHAR(63),
        Field9 VARCHAR(63),
        Field10 VARCHAR(63),
        Field11 VARCHAR(63),
        Field12 VARCHAR(63),
        Field13 VARCHAR(63),
        Field14 VARCHAR(63),
        Field15 VARCHAR(63),
        Field16 VARCHAR(63),
        Field17 VARCHAR(63),
        Field18 VARCHAR(63),
        Field19 VARCHAR(63),
        Field20 VARCHAR(63)
        );", MyConnection
        )

        MyConnection.Close()
    End Sub
```

I've been grappling with this for longer than I would care to admit, but can't find anything. All of the questions I've found that are similar to this are trying to do different things, or are using different versions of the program. Is there a problem with my connection, is this SQL command not possible here, is it formatted wrong, is my code just wrong, or is it anything else? Any help would be much appreciated.

Software-wise, I'm using Office 2016, so Access 2016 and Excel 2016. Programming-wise, I'm using VB.NET Framework 4.6.1, from within Visual Studio 2017.

**Edit:** The title issue has been resolved, however now the program is throwing an error for 'ExecuteNonQuery()', saying 'Operation is not supported for this type of object'. The new and revised code is:

```
Sub ImportSheet3(ByVal ImportFileName As String, ByVal Month As String)
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim SQLCode As String = "CREATE TABLE " + Month + Convert.ToString(YearSelected) + "
        (
        ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Field1 VARCHAR(63),
        Field2 VARCHAR(63),
        Field3 VARCHAR(63),
        Field4 VARCHAR(63),
        Field5 VARCHAR(63),
        Field6 VARCHAR(63),
        Field7 VARCHAR(63),
        Field8 VARCHAR(63),
        Field9 VARCHAR(63),
        Field10 VARCHAR(63),
        Field11 VARCHAR(63),
        Field12 VARCHAR(63),
        Field13 VARCHAR(63),
        Field14 VARCHAR(63),
        Field15 VARCHAR(63),
        Field16 VARCHAR(63),
        Field17 VARCHAR(63),
        Field18 VARCHAR(63),
        Field19 VARCHAR(63),
        Field20 VARCHAR(63)
        );"

        Try
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ImportFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0';")
            MyConnection.Open()
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLCode, MyConnection)

            MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MyCommand.Dispose()
            MyConnection.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not running the query. You created the connection, opened it, but didn't set anything to run, so it opens and closes without doing anything.

And use parameters to execute queries, instead of the text directly, to avoid any possible damage to your database. Anyway, without parameters it should look like this:

```
conn = New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
conn.Open()
Dim tb = "table"
Dim Sql = "CREATE TABLE " & tb & ";"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
conn.Dispose()
```

Enclosing it in a `Try Catch` block wouldn't be a bad idea, too.

Comment: It would be a good idea to mention the [OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2). Also, in this case, parameters can't be used, although enclosing the table name in square brackets would be prudent.

Comment: Update it again. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Wow, I was not expecting answers so quickly! I see now I need a line to execute the command, however the '.ExecuteNonQuery()' option doesn't come up.

Comment: You are using a table adapter instead of a Command. Change this `OleDbDataAdapter` to this `OleDbCommand`

Comment: Making progress, but now the program's thrown a new error on the '.ExecuteNonQuery()' command, saying: 'Operation is not supported for this type of object.' Not sure what the 'object' is in this case.

Comment: Your query is wrong, too. Change `ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` to `ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: No, the query isn't wrong, I'd tested it in Access beforehand. Changing to your suggestion gave a syntax error. Could I somehow publish my revised code here and start looking over it again?

Comment: Excuse me, but are you trying to execute the `CREATE TABLE` in an Excel File? If so, I don't think it's gonna work. You have to remove the `Extended Properties='Excel 12.0';` from the connection string and try to use the `CREATE TABLE` in a database.